# numpy.concatenate on record arrays fails when array has different length strings

Tags: python, numpy

When trying to concatenate record arrays which has a field of dtype string but has different length, concatenation fails.

As you can see in the following example, concatenate works if 'f1' is of same length but fails, if not.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([1,2], ["one","two"]) )

In [3]: b = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([3,4,5], ["three","four","three"]) )

In [4]: c = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([6], ["six"]) )

In [5]: np.concatenate( (a,c) )
Out[5]: 
array([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (6, 'six')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '|S3')])

In [6]: np.concatenate( (a,b) )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/u/jegannas/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

But, again if we just concatenate the arrays (not the records), it succeeds, though strings are of different size.

```
In [8]: np.concatenate( (a['f1'], b['f1']) )
Out[8]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'three'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Is this a bug in concatenate when concatenating records or is this the expected behavior. I have figured only the following way to overcome this.

```
In [10]: np.concatenate( (a.astype(b.dtype), b) )
Out[10]: 
array([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'three')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '|S5')]
```

But the trouble here is that I have to go through all the recarrays, I am concatenating and find the largest string length and I have to use that. If I have more than one string columns in the record array, I need to keep track of a few other things too.

What do you think is the best way to overcome this, at least for now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To post a complete answer. As Pierre GM suggested the module:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions
```

gives a solution. The function that does what you want however is:

```
numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays((a,b), autoconvert=True, usemask=False)
```

(`usemask=False` is just to avoid creation of a masked array, which you are probably not using. The important thing is `autoconvert=True` to force the conversion from `a`'s `dtype` `"|S3"` to `"|S5"`).

Answer (score 2):

When you do not specify the dtype, `np.rec.fromarrays` (aka `np.core.records.fromarrays`) tries to guess the dtype for you. Hence,

```
In [4]: a = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([1,2], ["one","two"]) )

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
rec.array([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S3')])
```

Notice the dtype of the `f1` column is a 3-byte string.

You can't concatenate `np.concatenate( (a,b) )` because numpy sees the dtypes of `a` and `b` are different and doesn't change the dtype of the smaller string to match the larger string.

If you know a maximum string size that would work with all your arrays, you could specify the dtype from the beginning:

```
In [9]: a = np.rec.fromarrays( ([1,2], ["one","two"]), dtype = [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S8')])

In [10]: b = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([3,4,5], ["three","four","three"]), dtype = [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S8')])
```

and then concatenation will work as desired:

```
In [11]: np.concatenate( (a,b))
Out[11]: 
array([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'three')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S8')])
```

---

If you do not know in advance the maximum length of the strings, you could specify the dtype as 'object':

```
In [35]: a = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([1,2], ["one","two"]), dtype = [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'object')])

In [36]: b = np.core.records.fromarrays( ([3,4,5], ["three","four","three"]), dtype = [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'object')])

In [37]: np.concatenate( (a,b))
Out[37]: 
array([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'three')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|O4')])
```

This will not be as space-efficient as a dtype of `'|Sn'` (for some integer `n`), but at least it will allow you to perform the `concatenate` operation.

Comment: I know that. And that is there in my question itself. All these individual array are generated by a sub module (which I have no control over). I just have to concatenate all these arrays.

Comment: Instead of keeping track of the maximum size of each of your arrays, I was suggesting that you choose in advance a number `n` that is sufficiently big to accomodate all the strings. This is different than the idea you propose in your question. However, if such a number `n` can not be known in advance, you could use the `'object'` dtype instead. I've edited my post to demonstrate this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Would `numpy.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays` work for you ? `recfunctions` is a little known subpackage that hasn't been advertised a lot, it's a bit clunky but could be useful sometimes.

Comment: What is the numpy version here. I don't see this.

Comment: @SenthilBabu you have to import it explicitely `import numpy.lib.recfunctions`. (Other then that it exists at least in 1.6

Comment: I don't think, I need `mergearrays`. It could be useful only if I have undefined values. Otherwise. `mergearrays` is identical to `numpy.core.records.fromarrays`

Comment: Indeed, however there is also stack_arrays that has the autoconvert keyword: `numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays((a,b), autoconvert=True, usemask=False)`