# Concatenation of every row combination of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Given two arrays (A and B) of different shapes, I've like to produce an array containing the concatenation of every row from A with every row from B.

E.g. given:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

B = np.array([[7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12]])
```

would like to produce the array:

```
[[1, 2, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 10, 11, 12],
 [3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
 [3, 4, 10, 11, 12],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [5, 6, 10, 11, 12]]
```

I can do this with iteration, but it's very slow, so looking for some combination of `numpy` functions that can recreate the above as efficiently as possible (the input arrays A and B will be up to 10,000 rows in size, hence looking to avoid nested loops).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfect problem to learn about [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and [`broadcasted-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Here's a vectorized solution using those tools -

```
def concatenate_per_row(A, B):
    m1,n1 = A.shape
    m2,n2 = B.shape

    out = np.zeros((m1,m2,n1+n2),dtype=A.dtype)
    out[:,:,:n1] = A[:,None,:]
    out[:,:,n1:] = B
    return out.reshape(m1*m2,-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [441]: A
Out[441]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [442]: B
Out[442]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

In [443]: concatenate_per_row(A, B)
Out[443]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 3,  4, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 5,  6, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: It's beautiful!

Comment: Thanks, works nicely, and has the side benefit of pre-allocating the output array, so ensures I have space for it up front.

Comment: @DaveChallis That's the whole idea there. With large arrays, any stacking operation is just *punishment*  speaking in terms of efficiency of memory/performance.

Comment: @Divakar, beautiful solution! If you have some time, could you give me a hint how this could be done using the broadcast_to function instead to force explicit broadcasting of concatenate. There is a discussion at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2115, but it is all based on wanting to join a (n,1) array rather than whole rows, and it does not actually use broadcast_to. I had trouble adapting it to a case where one array was (3,3) and another was (4,2) for example [looking for an answer of shape (12,5)]. Your solution here works for that, but was hoping to better grasp broadcast_to().

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [numpy.concatenate on record arrays fails when array has different length strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090345/numpy-concatenate-on-record-arrays-fails-when-array-has-different-length-strings)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import stack_arrays
from pprint import pprint

A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

B = np.array([[7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12]])

cartesian = [stack_arrays((a, b), usemask=False) for a in A
                                                 for b in B]

pprint(cartesian)
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 2, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([ 1,  2, 10, 11, 12]),
 array([3, 4, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([ 3,  4, 10, 11, 12]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([ 5,  6, 10, 11, 12])]
```